# Rails CanCan, failing unless I have a Rails.logger.info --- why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

If I have this:

```
can [:manage], GroupMember do |group_member|
  wall_member.try(:user_id) == current_user.id
  Rails.logger.info 'XXXX'
end
```

CanCan works properly but if I remove the logger, it fails:

```
can [:manage], GroupMember do |group_member|
  wall_member.try(:user_id) == current_user.id
end
```

Any ideas what's going on here with CanCan? or my code? :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://rdoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/master/CanCan/Ability#can-instance_method):

> If the conditions hash does not give you enough control over defining abilities, you can use a block along with any Ruby code you want.
>
> ```
> can :update, Project do |project|
>   project.groups.include?(user.group)
> end
> ```
>
> If the block returns true then the user has that :update ability for that project, otherwise he will be denied access. The downside to using a block is that it cannot be used to generate conditions for database queries.

Your first block:

```
can [:manage], GroupMember do |group_member|
  wall_member.try(:user_id) == current_user.id
  Rails.logger.info 'XXXX'
end
```

Will always return a true value because [`Rails.logger.info 'XXXX'`](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveSupport/BufferedLogger#add-instance_method) returns `"XXXX\n"` (`info` is just a wrapper for `add` and you have to read the source to see what `add` returns as it isn't very well documented). Without the `Rails.logger.info` call, the block returns just:

```
wall_member.try(:user_id) == current_user.id
```

and that must be false for you.